# Java Generics Compiler Error: What's wrong?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

I am currently trying to program an event system using generic Listeners. 
All listeners should be added to a single EventSource Object which will call their receiveEvent() methods for a specific event.

**EventSource**:

```
public class EventSource {

private HashMap<String, List<EventListener<? extends Event>>> events = new HashMap<>();

public synchronized <T extends Event> void fireEvent(T event){
    String key = event.getClass().getName();
    if(events.containsKey(key)){
        Iterator<EventListener<? extends Event>> i = events.get(key).iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            i.next().receiveEvent(event); //Compiler Error
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting error is:

> The method receiveEvent(capture#2-of ? extends Event) in the type EventListener is not applicable for the arguments (T)

**EventListener** is only:

```
public interface EventListener<T extends Event> {
    public void receiveEvent(T event);
}
```

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're iterating over a `List<EventListener<? extends Event>>`, but the compiler doesn't know which class, `Event` or a subclass of `Event`, the `?` wildcard could be.  The `T` type parameter could also be `Event` or any subclass of `Event`.  They do not match for this reason.

Try removing the wildcards:

```
// Removed wildcard
private HashMap<String, List<EventListener<Event>>> events = new HashMap<>();

public synchronized <T extends Event> void fireEvent(T event){
  String key = event.getClass().getName();
  if(events.containsKey(key)){
     // Removed wildcard.
     Iterator<EventListener<Event>> i = events.get(key).iterator();
     while(i.hasNext()){
        i.next().receiveEvent(event); // This compiles now.
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot that works. But I'm still not really getting why this doesn't work. When i am initializing a field of the type `Class<? extends Event>` with an object of the type `Class<T extends Event>` what actually works, wouldn't that have the same error?

Comment: Imagine 2 `Event` subclasses, `Event1` and `Event2`.  The `T` in theory could in reality be `Event1` and the `?` could be `Event2`, in which case they would be incompatible.  The compiler's job with generics is to ensure type safety, and because of this possibility, it must disallow passing what could be an incompatible parameter to the method.

Comment: Okay, I think I kind of get it. Thanks a lot!